# Only trigger a javascript function when checkbox is checked "on"

Tags: javascript

This script causes the alert to show regardless of whether the checkbox is being ticked on or off. How can it only show when the tick box is being clicked on?

```
$("#x").click(function() {
    alert("Ticker is has been clicked on!");
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f4Tmu/22/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an `if` statement inside the function to test for that:

```
$("#x").click(function() {
    if (this.checked) alert("Ticker is has been clicked on!");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

//use .is(':checked') to check if it was checked!

```
$("#x").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert("Ticker is has been clicked on!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `if` conditional will do the trick for you:

```
$("#x").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        alert("Ticker is has been clicked on!");
    }
});
```

Check out some reading on the [.is() method](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and [:checked selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) within jQuery.